# #1100 - Table 'pma__tracking' was not locked with LOCK TABLES - PHPMyAdmin, easyPHP

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to simply run a table creation script on PHPMyadmin; using easyPHP. and it is giving me this issue:

```
#1100 - Table 'pma__tracking' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

When I run the script on WAMP server's PHPMyadmin I do not encounter this issue. the script successfully executes. same script. Same version of PHPmyadmin on both.

I can't find any help on the internet, I'm assuming this has to do with user permissions?

This is the latest version of easyPHP.

Any ideas what creates this error, and how I should go about fixing it?

Answer (score 16):

Look into your phpMyAdmin config.inc.php file, there should be :

```
/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'your_root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'your_password';
```

Comment: It is a solution that works, however I'd be curious if there's another way (I'm wondering if pma actually needs root access for its control db operations)

Comment: Ye, not a huge fan of having root user even having a password tbh

Answer (score 6):

Solution is simple,

Open the .SQL file in a notepad and

find

```
 LOCK TABLES
```

and replace it by

```
 #LOCK TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your sql file in any editor

find  LOCK TABLES and replace it with #LOCK TABLES